# Scraping tabular data with Python-BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Can't figure out how to scrape the first table data instead of both.

```
<tr>
<td>WheelDust
</td>
<td>A large puff of barely visible brown dust
</td></tr>
```

I only want WheelDust but instead I get WheelDust and A large puff of barely visible brown dust

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


r = requests.get("https://wiki.garrysmod.com/page/Effects")

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

for td in soup.findAll("table"):
    #--print(td)
    for a in td.findAll("tr"):
        print(a.text)
```

Comment: You could use soup.find intsead of soup.find_all if you don't want to keep iterating after the first find. You can also use 'break' when you find 'WheelDust'.

Comment: Yeah, but this is a table so I wanna find everything in the first category

Comment: Why don't you do a.find('td') after you enter the tr?

Comment: I don't get what you mean, can you post an answer with what you're saying? I'm already getting the td. The problem i'm having is I just want the name, not the description. WheelDust = name, description = A large puff of barely visible brown dust. so I only want the name when I iterate, not the description..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not sure what you're asking, but I believe you're saying that you want to access the  and only the first , correct? If that's the case, would this not work? I'd try it but it says I don't have access to the website.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


r = requests.get("https://wiki.garrysmod.com/page/Effects")

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

for td in soup.findAll("table"):
    #--print(td)
    for a in td.findAll("tr"):
        print(a.find('td'))
```

Comment: Oh, that is what i'm looking for. I haven't seen it done that way. thank you. when I add the text attribute it doesn't return me the text but instead the text with the tags

Comment: Yup! That sounds reasonable. Feel free to tick the check-mark once you've solved your issue so that the problem is marked as done.

Answer (score 0):

Try this as well. It will give you all the data from that table.

```
import requests ; from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get("https://wiki.garrysmod.com/page/Effects").text, "html.parser")

table = soup.findAll('table', attrs={'class':'wikitable'})[0] # Changing the index number will give you whichever table you like
list_of_rows = [[t_data.text for t_data in item.findAll('td')]
                for item in table.findAll('tr')]

for data in list_of_rows:
    print(data)
```